Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) Jobs Failing After Upgrading to OpenJDK 11 on CentOS VM
I recently upgraded my Java version from 8 to 11 (openjdk 11.0.22 2024-01-16 LTS
) on a CentOS virtual machine where I run Pentaho Data Integration (PDI) jobs. According to documentation, PDI 9.3 should be compatible with OpenJDK 11. However, after the upgrade, my PDI jobs started failing with the following error:
-Djava.endorsed.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jre/jre/lib/endorsed:/usr/lib/jvm/jre/lib/endorsed:/home/pentaho/pentaho-ce/data-integration/system/karaf/lib/endorsed is not supported. Endorsed standards and standalone APIs
in modular form will be supported via the concept of upgradeable modules.
Error: Could not create the Java Virtual Machine.
Error: A fatal exception has occurred. Program will exit.

First question is why Spoon even points to the libraries that do not exist in Java 11 if they claim to support this version?
Workaround:
I had to comment these lines in the spoon.sh file to make it work:

It works now, but it takes around 7 minutes to start an ETL job, and then pauses several times in between with the log entries like this:
[1056.704s][info   ][gc] GC(575) Pause Young (Prepare Mixed) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2930M->2748M(2942M) 10.937ms
[1056.952s][info   ][gc] GC(576) Pause Young (Mixed) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2888M->2758M(2942M) 20.068ms
[1057.310s][info   ][gc] GC(577) Pause Young (Concurrent Start) (G1 Evacuation Pause) 2884M->2759M(2942M) 23.563ms
[1057.310s][info   ][gc] GC(578) Concurrent Cycle
[1058.085s][info   ][gc] GC(578) Pause Remark 2867M->2861M(2942M) 13.022ms
[1058.577s][info   ][gc] GC(578) Pause Cleanup 2883M->2883M(2942M) 0.773ms
[1058.582s][info   ][gc] GC(578) Concurrent Cycle 1271.535ms

Any recommendations on how to handle this better?

"First question is why Spoon even points to the libraries that do not exist in Java 11 if they claim to support this version?" That is a question for the supplier, not for Stackoverlow.

@aled - That's a valid point. I figured someone here might already be familiar with it since the Pentaho community is slow. That's why I posted the question here.
